# Can we restore support for the "+" operator in the global SE search?

Tags: feature-request, search, stackexchange.com

The global network search at [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com) uses Google search (though it doesn't show that on the homepage).

[image]

Since Google has [dropped the plus character for indicating required search terms](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/websearch/finding-stuff-on-google/3oIWbew9xdE), the operators on regular sites and the global site no longer match.

For example:

- `multi user +vpn +windows` has no hits [on Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=multi+user+%2Bvpn+%2Bwindows), but does [on Super User](https://superuser.com/search?q=multi+user+%2Bvpn+%2Bwindows).
- `multi user "vpn" "windows"` does show results [on Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=multi+user+%22vpn%22+%22windows%22).

As a possible workaround for Google's change, is there any chance that SE could replace `+term` with `"term"` before submitting it to Google?

(I'd rather *not* see SE drop support for the `+` as well...!)

Comment: When I use `+` on google.com, it is silently dropped, instead of displaying no results at all. Strange that it behaves differently on SE.

Comment: [Indeed](https://www.google.com/#q=multi+user+%2Bvpn+%2Bwindows),  [silently dropped](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uOfAh.png) on Google, but apparently not when limiting to a site. Like it's [not **silently**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uUA3G.png) dropping it for me when searching for [site:superuser.com multi user +vpn +windows](https://www.google.com/#q=site:superuser.com+multi+user+%2Bvpn+%2Bwindows). (But even then it's automatically showing the results without punctuation, while also referring me [to some help](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?p=g_punctuation&answer=2466433).)

Comment: (Hmmm, [only 17 results](https://www.google.com/#q=multi+user+%2Bvpn+%2Bwindows) when "silently dropping" it. So: not *really* dropping it? When using quotes, [far more results](https://www.google.com/#q=multi+user+%22vpn%22+%22windows%22)...)

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the search box to obey the rules of whatever engine it is using.  Even if that engine makes weird suboptimal decisions to drop the + operator.

This would mean the search box is more predictable - I know it's obeying the rules, and I don't have to think about whether the latest change by the search engine has been patched by SE.

But, whatever happens, I think it's important to give a link to correct information about what your search box requires.

As an aside, Stack Exchange is an example of a group of people who are most affected by the dropping of the plus operator.  SE users are the few users who would have used this feature correctly.  Google has said that only 0.5% of searches used the plus operator and two thirds of the time it was used wrong.  (Check my math, but that's 3 in 600 using it, 2 of those 3 wrong and only 1 in 600 using it correctly.) [Here's a link to a Google Blog post about dropping the plus operator, changing to "verbatim search", with the numbers.](http://insidesearch.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/search-using-your-terms-verbatim.html)

Comment: How did you get to this question...? As for *"obey the rules of whatever engine it is using"* I'd say: as SE is not making clear what *non-SE* engine it's using, I'd simply expect it to confirm to its own SE search engine grammar.

Comment: @Arjan it has always been google on se.com...not that there's a secret whole-network search URL on top of elastic I need to work on when time allows or anything...