# How can I search multiple sites for my posts about a *nix question at once?

Tags: feature-request, search, multiple-accounts

Sometimes I know I have previously posted an answer (or a question) about something.
For example, I just wanted to find an answer I had posted about modifying my `.bashrc` shell.
The search is specific to 'me' so "[Is there a way to search all sites at once?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70331/is-there-a-way-to-search-all-sites-at-once)" doesn't help.
The search is across sites so "[How can I search within my own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27487/how-can-I-search-within-my-own-questions)" didn't seem to help either.

My answer is probably in **Unix & Linux**.

But it might be **Ask Ubuntu**.

Of course it might just be in **Stack Overflow**, especially if it's old.

Or maybe I put it in **Super User** and no-one moved it.

How can I search all the sites that I am registered with, given that I have different user id's on each site (only 1 login but they all have different `user:nnnnn` id's).

This is an invaluable feature because I like to use Stack Exchange as my 'knowledge base' for all the stuff I know – and of course I'm helping out others in the process – but without this search I am :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Stack Exchange.com search lets you include user names](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Michael%20Durrant%20bashrc%20%20shell) just like Google does (it IS Google search) while whittling down the query to all SE sites (plus 3 ads at the top). It's a lot better than trying to shoehorn a regular Google search into `site:stackexchange.com site:stackoverflow` ect

Comment: thank you for the tip. however I wanted to seach infavorites:mine and it returned not only mine results. what features does this search support (there is no help button as opposed to search on individual site)?

Answer (score 1):

Google indexes the full pages, including your name wherever that is mentioned. So, adding that to the search query might help, for those with a user name that is not too common and is not @mentioned in comments a lot.

Still, this feels like a workaround to me, just as long there's no real network wide search.

(Put your name in double quotes [to make Google include it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126835/can-we-restore-support-for-the-operator-in-the-global-se-search).)