# Can the multi-site search for my stuff ui be improved via a checkbox "my posts only'?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface

I just asked this:
[How can I search multiple sites for my posts about a *nix question at once?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136352/how-can-i-search-multiple-sites-for-my-posts-about-a-nix-question-at-once) and I like the answer.

I am wondering though if it might be possible (and a good idea...) to have, say, a checkbox to help with this.

So that instead of using `"michael durrant" bash` to search across multiple sites, one could just use `bash` and then check-off something like 'Only`search your posts?` or `my posts only` or something.

Could also be an advanced feature to users with, say 5000+ combined rep to get the basic ui clean and simple and unconfusing for new folks.

References:
https://stackoverflow.com/search
[Additional search features/syntax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1114/additional-search-features-syntax)

Comment: Using your full name might work [for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69256/is-it-bad-to-use-your-real-name-as-your-user-name), but just using "Arjan" without a last name, is a different thing already. This all feels like a workaround for not having a true network wide search.